# Security Risks Associated With Local Web Servers

Tags: apache, wamp, server

If I set up a local server using, say, Apache or WAMP are there any associated security risks? I'm not planning on hosting or making any content "publicly accessible," I just want to set up an environment where I can learn PHP and develop using an HTML5 game engine. Sorry if this is a completely naive question; I'm just a bit confused about how server security works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't open up any ports in your router to allow for public access to your web server, then it won't add any security risks. Just installing the local web server won't do this.

On a side note, WAMP is a collection of tools that includes Apache as the web server, they are not examples of two different web servers.